# Python Selenium How to locate and fill up this 3 inputs

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

i'm trying to fill up that form (you have to be logged into facebook) :
**https://m.facebook.com/marketplace/selling/item/** . I've already done 3 inputs ( what u selling - price - description ) but i didn't know how to fill up the 3 others ( Category - Photos - Location )

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

#OpenBrowser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://facebook.com/")

#Logging
email = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('pass')
#facebook username input
email.send_keys('email')
#facebook password input
password.send_keys('pass')

time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()
#Redicret to fb marketplace
time.sleep(2)
driver.get("https://m.facebook.com/marketplace/selling/item/"

#Filling up form
time.sleep(5)
title = driver.find_element_by_name('title').send_keys('title teste')

time.sleep(2)
price = driver.find_element_by_name('price').send_keys('50')

time.sleep(2)
description = driver.find_element_by_name('description').send_keys('description teste')
```

[Form that i'm trying to fill up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOQlv.png)